# Can't delete S3 buckets - Error Data not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't get rid of five buckets in S3. Every screen in the AWS console says "Error Data not found" (i.e. Overview, Properties, Permissions, Management, Access points).

I can't set **lifecycle** rules to delete objects, but the buckets never had anything in them and versioning was never enabled anyway.

I've also tried forcing it in my terminal...

`aws s3 rb s3://bucketblah --force`

...but it fails and I get *remove_bucket failed: Unable to delete all objects in the bucket, bucket will not be deleted.*

Help me Obi Wan...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Amazon S3 is what gives a developer their power. It's an energy field created by objects stored in the cloud. It surrounds us and penetrates us. It binds the Internet together.

Some may mock Amazon S3 because they cannot sense invisible objects in their bucket. But the wise Jedi amongst us will check whether the bucket has Versioning enabled. When attempting to rid the galaxy of their bucket, they might see messages such as:

```
$ aws s3 rb s3://rebel-base --force
```

> remove_bucket failed: An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The rebel base you tried to destroy is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.

If such resistance is met, sneak into the Amazon S3 management console, select the bucket, choose `Versions: Show` and reach out with your mind. If any deleted versions of objects are displayed, delete them within this view until all objects cry out in terror and are suddenly silenced.

If this does not lead to the resolution you seek, then check that your Master has allocated sufficient access privileges for you to access the central computer and this particular bucket. It is also possible that these buckets have **bucket policies** that override the central computer via `Deny` policies. If so, attempt to bypass security by deleting the bucket policy first, then destroy the rebel bucket. You know better than to trust a strange computer!

Comment: You are awesome. I have used mind. I have used saber. I have tried everything you mentioned. I am the master of my buckets and domain. But alas, the buckets persist. Behold this image provided by R2-D2. http://k1r.com/images/

Comment: There are legends that such problems occur when buckets are on a journey through hyperspace and they dematerialize correctly after the journey is complete. Please wait two parsecs and check again. Failing this, it may be necessary to pay a visit to the Sith Lords at AWS Support and request their assistance. They might be your only hope.

Comment: Thank you, wise one. I will wait to see what the wind brings.

Comment: The gears of the death star are slow to turn, but by the gods, all pesky X-wing fighter buckets have been exfoliated from the surface of S3 automatically. Perhaps the free tier get fewer server resources.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply, for me each time I try to delete the bucket it would say "Not Found"

Even when I tried clicking on the bucket it said not found.

I had to create a bucket with the same name (which it allowed me to). Then delete that bucket. Extremely strange but it worked.