# S3 buckets are corrupted, how to remove?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Created two buckets in S3 using a `python` script, but the script was terminated a few seconds into it, seemingly resulting in a bad bucket state.  The same code has created similar buckets before without issue and they appear in the correct region.

[image]

Trying to delete through AWS dashboard yields the following error.

[image]

Furthermore, `boto3` access via `list_buckets` does not include these in the list.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Force-refresh the S3 console page that lists buckets to be sure they actually exist.

Comment: @jarmod what does that mean?

Comment: You said that boto3 list_buckets does not show this bucket yet the S3 console does show it. I'm asking you to rule out a cached bucket listing in the S3 console. Also, what does the awscli or boto3 tell you if you use them to attempt to delete this bucket?

Comment: Sometimes, a deleted bucket takes a while to disappear. Wait for a day and you'll probably find that it has successfully been deleted. See: [Can't delete S3 buckets - Error Data not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472451/174777)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein - it went away itself after 6 hours or so.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this piece of code works, if you run this on cli.
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket-name --force

Comment: that could works but if there is not versioning enabled in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Waited 6 hours or so and it corrected it5self as @John Rotenstein said may happen in comment